# Using wp_mail, emails not received in Gmail account only (Yahoo & Hotmail are fine)

Tags: email, wordpress, gmail

I created a new custom page in WordPress to test sending emails and this is my code...

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:testemail
*/

get_header();
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name' );
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
function my_mail_from_name( $name )
{
    return 'nameeeeee';
}

wp_mail('salwaieh@gmail.com', 'The subject1', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>');
wp_mail('salwaieh2012@gmail.com', 'The subjectx', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>');
wp_mail('salwaieh@hotmail.com', 'The subject2', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>');
wp_mail('salwaieh@yahoo.com', 'The subject3', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>');
$to      = 'salwaieh@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'The subject4';
$message = 'The subject4 The subject4 The subject4The subject4 The subject4 The subject4';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


$to      = 'salwaieh2012@gmail.com';
$subject = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$message = 'The subject4 The subject4 The subject4The subject4 The subject4 The subject4';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


get_footer(); ?>
```

I received all emails to Yahoo and Hotmail accounts but why I can't find any email in my Gmail inbox?

Comment: dont use example.com and xxxxxx subject to test on gmail. I would rather do with a random 2 or more character strings. Also check your spam as Oliver said.

Answer (score 0):

Many email services recently got really strict about spam, so I have been having problems with all of my Wordpress contact forms.  I ended up fixing the problem with the wp-smtp plugin.  It is more of a work-around than an actual solution though...